# WPF inherited property change notification

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, attached-properties

How to make an inherited property changes to update a custom control?

I have defined view model `Circle` with property `Radius` as:

```
public class Circle : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Circle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0));

    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }        

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() =>
        new Circle();            
}
```

Now comes the control itself with couple of properties: `Direct` (`AffectsRender`) and `Inherited` (`AffectsRender|Inherits`) of type `Circle`:

```
class View : FrameworkElement
{
    // Inherited

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InheritedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Inherited", typeof(Circle), typeof(View),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    null, 
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | 
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static void SetInherited(UIElement element, Circle value)
    {
        element.SetValue(InheritedProperty, value);
    }

    public static Circle GetInherited(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Circle)element.GetValue(InheritedProperty);
    }

    public Circle Inherited
    {
        get { return GetInherited(this); }
        set { SetInherited(this, value); }
    }

    // Direct

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Direct", typeof(Circle), typeof(View),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    null, 
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static void SetDirect(UIElement element, Circle value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DirectProperty, value);
    }

    public static Circle GetDirect(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Circle)element.GetValue(DirectProperty);
    }

    public Circle Direct
    {
        get { return GetDirect(this); }
        set { SetDirect(this, value); }
    }

    // Render

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black, null, 
            new Point(), Inherited.Radius, Direct.Radius);
    }
}
```

Now the question. This way:

```
<local:View x:Name="_view">
    <local:View.Inherited>
        <local:Circle/>
    </local:View.Inherited>
    <local:View.Direct>
        <local:Circle/>
    </local:View.Direct>
</local:View>
```

The following code re-renders the view:

```
    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _view.Inherited.Radius+=10;
    }

    private void Window_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _view.Direct.Radius++;
    }
```

But when XAML looks this way:

```
<local:View.Inherited>
    <local:Circle/>
</local:View.Inherited>
<local:View x:Name="_view">
    <local:View.Direct>
        <local:Circle/>
    </local:View.Direct>
</local:View>
```

This line stops updating the screen:

```
_view.Inherited.Radius+=10;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Interestingly, it works if you just use `double` instead of `Circle` as type of the `Direct` and `Inherited` properties.

Comment: Also interesting, it doesn't work for both properties if Circle is not a Freezable, but just a DependencyObject. You should probably not rely at all on the mechanism that value changes of a sub-property trigger the rendering. Besides that using dependency properties in view models looks odd anyway.

Comment: @Clemens Yep, only Freezable supports sub-property change notification throw the Changed event to work with things like a Pen or Brush. Actually, I am building some simple charting library and would like visual parts of my chart to speak with each other – like TopRuler and Plot being sharing inheritable attached property Plot.XAxis of type Axis with some sub-properties and methods.